# How do I align textview.text with edittext.text

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried a lot of different attribute values, but no result yet.
No pictures allowed.
But the text in the edittext.text remains about *3 mm to high*.

One Solution is to "compensate" the "error" in **?android:attr/editTextBackgroud.**  This last one seems to sneek in witout clear warning or expectation.

```
textView: paddingbottom=14
editText layout_marginTop=10
editText background=?android:attr/editTextBackground
```

Comment: can you clarify what you want - exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_alignBaseline in your edit text

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/your_textview_id"
```

Comment: That is not alowed in a linearlayout.  I'll try switching to a relativelayout

Comment: Yes it has to be relative layout.